# Covariance matrix as a linear transformation

Tags: random-variable, linear, covariance-matrix

I am trying to understand the general relationship between the covariance between two random variables and linear transformations. For example, consider the figure here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance#/media/File:Covariance_trends.svg

The bottom figure seems to resemble a sort of shear transformation of the middle figure. Can this intuition be formalized? It seems to me that the covariance matrix in general acts as a linear transformation on a random vector of uncorrelated random variables.

Comment: I'd recommend looking at other questions here on PCA and SVD.  But the "random vector of uncorrelated random variables" (I'd call it a matrix) you mentioned is basically the matrix U from the SVD.  Then the matrices Sigma and V represent the shearing you talk about.

Comment: @MathFoliage Ok, so is $[X'X]^{-1}X'$ in the standard linear regression the pseudoinverse from SVD?

Comment: yes it is.  The pseudoinverse can be obtained by transposing the SVD and inverting the singular values on the diagonal of Sigma.

Comment: @MathFoliage Ok, and to connect this back to my question about the covariance matrix, is the linkage to the covariance matrix via $M^{T}M$, as discussed here (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1101022/relation-between-covariance-matrix-and-svd-of-a-given-matrix)?

Comment: Yeah, in that question M is the same as X in your comment about the pseudoinverse.  It's just the matrix of centered data.